# Update submodule referencing to a local repository via ssh

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a remote server (example.com) which hosts both Apache and Git.

On my local dev machine I cloned Repository_A from example.com, added Repository_B (also hosted at example.com) as submodule of Repository_A and pushed it back.

The submodules path is `ssh://dev@example.com:/var/git/themes/Repository_B.git`.

On the next step I want to clone Repository_A into the webroot of the server. I do:

> git clone /var/git/sites/Repository_A.git
>   git submodule init
>   git submodule update

And get the following error:

```
Cloning into sites/all/themes/Repository_B...  
ssh: Could not resolve hostname example.com:: Name or service not known
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly  
Clone of 'ssh://dev@example.com:/var/git/themes/Repository_B.git' into submodule path 'sites/all/themes/Repository_B' failed
```

However, I can ssh from example.com into example.com without any problems.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: One extra colon in the URL: ssh://dev@example.com:/var/git/themes/Repository_B.git after host name

Comment: It should be ssh://dev@example.com/var/git/themes/Repository_B

Comment: This works, thank you! Wondering about the downvote btw.

Comment: I didn't downvoted it, somebody else did. Anyway, it's not a big deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by user3159253 the submodule URL should be without colon after the domain.

ssh://dev@example.com/var/git/themes/Repository_B